# In Judith 14:17, why did everybody strip off their clothing ("sciderunt omnes vestimenta sua") when they heard Holofernes died?

Tags: latin-vulgate, judith

In Judith 14:17, why did everybody strip off their clothing ("sciderunt omnes vestimenta sua") when they heard Holofernes died? Was that some kind of custom back then? If so, it was definitely a weird one.

Comment: [Sciderunt](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sciderunt) comes from [scindo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scindo#Latin), which is related to the English [scissor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scissor).

Comment: @Lucian That... does not address my question.

Comment: Why doesn't it ? :-) They tore or rent their clothing, not stripped it.

Comment: @Lucian Sorry, English is not my native language (I am Croatian), what is the difference?

Comment: Stripping means taking one's clothes off, as in *strip tease*; tearing or rending means ripping them apart to shreds.

Comment: @Lucian OK, sorry, I assumed "scindo" means the same as Croatian "skinuti". Are "scindo" and "skinuti" related at all, or is that a false cognate?

Answer (score 0):

The  [Douay-Rheims English Translation](https://vulgate.org/ot/judith_14.htm) of the Vulgate reads:

> Now when the chiefs of the army of the Assyrians had heard this, they
> all rent their garments, and an intolerable fear and dread fell upon
> them, and their minds were troubled exceedingly.

The Vulgate conforms to the Greek version of Judith 14:19, which translates as:

> When the leaders of the Assyrian forces heard these words, they tore
> their tunics and were overcome with great distress. Their loud cries
> and shouts were heard throughout the camp. (NABRE translation)

The [Latin word *sciderunt*](https://www.wordsense.eu/sciderunt/) is normally translated as "tear" or "cut." It may tear off a strip of cloth but does not necessarily imply the removal of all of one's clothing.

**As to why the Assyrian army did this, the answer is that their leader had been killed. They did this to express their grief and anger. [Tearing one's garment](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/the-basics-of-kriah-or-tearing-a-piece-of-clothing/) at the death of a leader or loved one was a custom that the Israelites and the Assyrians had in common. Jews still do this today.**

Comment: Please consider limiting the use of bold formatting. Entire sentences/paragraphs that are bold become more difficult for users who are visually impaired.